# Beacon detection in android while application is killed

Tags: android, region, ibeacon-android

I managed to get the local notifications to work in my app, when the app is running in the background. I needed to know if I can still be able to get local notifications if the application is killed, it is swiped off from the background and a beacon is nearby the device? Is this possible in Android? If yes,then please let me know how this can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this functionality is built in to the <strike>Pro version of the</strike> [Android iBeacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/).  The library will automatically start scanning for beacons in the background after phone boot, and will call your app to let it launch local notifications when beacons are detected.

If a user later kills the app with the task switcher, this will only temporarily halt these detections, as the scanning service will automatically restart itself.  Details are [here.](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html)

Comment: is there example code on how this might work?  Also I appreciate all the work you have done on this :)

Comment: Here is a description that links to sample code: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/pro/background_launching.html

Comment: @davidgyoung : Is there any time range for the background scanning to take place in case the application is killed?? I had checked the phone reboot which works. And there is one more query I would like to add,I wasn't able to detect any ibeacons in an ipad having os version 7.0.4 and while downloading the "locate ibeacon" app from radius networks I was prompted that no BLE is available in your device.Can you please confirm if it is device specific issue or os specific issue??

Comment: If you have a first or second generation iPad, they do not have Bluetooth 4.0 (BLE) hardware, so you will not be able to detect iBeacons.  There is no preset time for the Android library to detect again after an app is killed, it is event based.  Full details are here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/pro/resume_after_terminate.html

Comment: @davidgyoung : I have one more query to ask,I basically need to setup radius network using titanium sdk for javascript.Is there any way to integrate it titanium?

Comment: I am unaware of any such effort even though equivalent ones exist for similar Cordova, Xamarin and B4A frameworks.  It may be worth asking asa new question to catch the attention of Titanium developers.

Comment: @davidgyoung : Yeah sure will do so.Thanks :)

Comment: @davidgyoung The link you mentioned for  "Pro version of the Android iBeacon Library" is showing "404 Not found" .  If possible please update the answer .

Comment: Updated!  The pro version was folded in to the standard version 2 1/2  years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You should write a service, and triggered it when device boot. :) You dont need to start app.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Can you please help me with a sample code to begin with as I am a newbie in Android?

Comment: you can use radius network's open source code. You implement beacon-search in IBeaconService and On manifest, add boot receiver for this service.

https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service